# Calculate $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{0\leqslant k\leqslant2n}\frac k{k+n^2}$ using Riemann sums

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, riemann-sum

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum\limits_{0\leqslant{k}\leqslant{2n}} {\frac{k}{k+n^{2}}}$$

I can't figure out the "right" function for this limit. The previous problem was very similar except there was $k^2$ in the denominator, and it wasn't difficult to recognize the Riemann sum for $f(x)=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$.

Given the limits, this integral sum can be written as $\sum{f(\frac{2k}{n})\cdot\frac{2}{n}}$.

Comment: "Given the limits, this integral sum can be written as $\sum{f(\frac{2k}{n})\cdot\frac{2}{n}}$." Well, no.

Comment: Sorry, but why not?

Comment: Which function $f$ would yield this identity? Not $f(x)=\frac x{x^2+1}$ in any case...

Comment: Or, alternatively, we can divide $[0;2]$ into $2n$ parts with the increment equal to $\frac{1}{n}$. Then the integral sum is the sum of $f(\frac{k}{n})\cdot\frac{1}{n}$ on $[0,2]$

Comment: No. Check your computations.

Comment: I have checked my computations several times. Can you, please, be a little bit more specific? This is my approach. Since $0\leqslant{k}\leqslant{2n}$, $0\leqslant{\frac{k}{n}}\leqslant{2}$. 

If we divide $[0,2]$ into $2n$ pieces where $x_{k+1}-x_{k}=\frac{1}{n}$ we can conclude that this expression can be written in the way I mentioned above. I guess that there's a hole in my reasoning, but I can't find out where exactly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82061/discussion-between-timur-sharapov-and-did).

Comment: If $f(x)=\frac x{1+x^2}$ then $\frac1n\cdot f\left(\frac kn\right)=\frac k{k^2+n^2}$, not $\frac k{k+n^2}$.

Comment: "Let us continue this discussion in chat." No thanks. Instead, just take seriously what people are taking the trouble of explaining to you.

Answer (score 2):

Write the sum as

$$S_{nn} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{k/n}{1 + k/n^2}$$

This is not in the form of a Riemann sum. However, there is a trick (requiring justification) where we can reduce the limit to that of a Riemann sum by viewing this in terms of a double sequence

$$S_{nm} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{k/n}{1 + (k/n)(1/m)}$$

Clearly, $\displaystyle\lim_{m \to \infty} S_{nm} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{k}{n}.\,$  As the convergence can be shown to be uniform for all $n$, by a well-known theorem for double sequences, we can evaluate as an iterated limit,

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} S_{nn} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \lim_{m \to \infty} S_{nm} = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{k}{n} = \int_0^2 x \, dx = 2.$$

**Justification: Uniform convergence of inner limit**

Note that

$$\left|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{k/n}{1 + (k/n)(1/m)} - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n} \frac{k}{n} \right|= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{(k/n)^2(1/m)}{1 + (k/n)(1/m)} \\ \leqslant \frac{1}{nm}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^2 \leqslant \frac{2n }{nm}\left(\frac{2n}{n} \right)^2 = \frac{8}{m}$$

Answer (score 0):

Edited after reading the comments.

No need for Riemann sums.

Lower bound:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{k}{k+n^2}\ge\frac{1}{2\,n+n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}k=\frac{n\,(2\,n+1)}{2\,n+n^2}.
$$
Upper boud:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{k}{k+n^2}\le\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}k=\frac{n\,(2\,n+1)}{n^2}.
$$
However, Riemann sums can be used, but in a more complicated way:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{k}{k+n^2}=2\,n\,\Bigl(\frac{1}{2\,n}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{k/(2\,n)}{k/(2\,n)+n/2}\Bigr)
\sim2\,n\int_0^1\frac{x\,dx}{x+n/2}.
$$

Comment: Simpler upper bound: $$
\sum_{k=0}^{2n}\frac{k}{k+n^2}\leqslant\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{k=0}^{2n}k$$

Comment: So there is no simple way to calculate this limit as the Riemann sum for some $f(x)$ without trying to bound the sum?

Comment: @TimurSharapov Indeed Riemann sums only complicate things here while simple uniform comparisons do the job neatly.

Comment: @Did I tried that type of estimate, and somehow forgot the $2$ in the denominator of the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{2n}k$.

Comment: Thus, modify your answer?